# El literal de objeto solo puede especificar propiedades conocidas y 'x' no existe en el tipo 'never[]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, context, reducer

Hace poco que estoy aprendiendo React JS y me encuentro realizando una pequeña app con Reactjs y Typescript. Tengo un archivo donde creo un Context el cual exporto y lo consumo en otro archivo de provider, a su vez tengo un otro archivo Reducer el cual manejara mi estado, el problema surge cuando trato de pasar el reducer a mi .providre value={{ AQUI }} me da un error:

" TS2322: Type '{ vehiculoState: VehiculoState; dispatch: React.Dispatch; }' is not assignable to type 'never[]'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'vehiculoState' does not exist in type 'never[]'. "

Explicare a mas detalle.

Tengo estas interfaces:

```
export interface Vehiculo {
    patente: string,
    horaEntrada: string,
    horaSalida: string,
    pagado: boolean,
    monto: number
}

export interface VehiculoState {
    vehiculos: Vehiculo[]
}

export interface VehiculoProviderProps {
    children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[]
}
```

Tengo este contexto

```
import { createContext } from "react";


export const VehiculoContext = createContext([])
```

El contexto es consumido en mi archivo de Provider

```
import { useReducer } from "react"
import { VehiculoProviderProps, VehiculoState } from '../interfaces/interfaces';
import { VehiculoContext } from "./VehiculoContext"
import { vehiculoReducer } from "./VehiculoReducer"

const INITIAL_STATE: VehiculoState = {
    vehiculos: [
        {
            patente: 'WL9925',
            horaEntrada: '09:00 27/02/2023',
            horaSalida: '10:00 27/02/2023',
            pagado: false,
            monto: 500
        },
    ]
}

export const VehiculoProvider = ({ children }: VehiculoProviderProps) => {

    const [ vehiculoState, dispatch ] = useReducer( vehiculoReducer, INITIAL_STATE )

    return (
        <>
            <VehiculoContext.Provider value={ {vehiculoState, dispatch}}>
                {children}
            </VehiculoContext.Provider>
        </>
    )
}
```

En este Provider deseo ocupar un reducer con el useReducer() este recibe el reducer y el estado inicial

Dejo imagen del reducer que cree:

```
import { Vehiculo, VehiculoState } from "../interfaces/interfaces";

type ActionVehiculo =
    | { type: 'addVehiculo', payload: Vehiculo }
    | { type: 'deleteVehiculo', payload: { patente: string} }


export const vehiculoReducer = (state: VehiculoState, action: ActionVehiculo): VehiculoState => {
    switch ( action.type ) {
        case 'addVehiculo':
            return {
                ...state,
                vehiculos: [ ...state.vehiculos, action.payload ]
            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

El problema surge cuando trato de pasar los valores al .Provider en el campo value es ahi domde TS me marca un error

[image: Error]

Trate de hacerlo con un useState pero al pasarle el estado inical no hay problema pero cuando trate de pasarlo en el .Provider value={{}} me da el mismo error

Espero obtener alguna ayuna desde ya muchas gracias.

PD: dejo package.json

```
{
  "name": "parking",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.32",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.4",
    "bulma": "^0.9.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-router-dom": "^6.11.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: El código como texto por favor.

Comment: Ahi master, debajo de cada imagen el codigo como texto

Comment: Las imagenes no sirven, y solo molestan del codigo como texto.. no se pueden copiar, no se pueden compilar... solo el texto porfa...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiero crear una `interface` para darle un `signature` al `context`:

```
interface ContextType {
    vehiculoState: VehiculoState;
    dispatch: Dispatch<any>;
}
```

Luego:

```
const VehiculoContext = createContext<ContextType | null>(null);
```

Con esto debería ser suficiente para que el provider acepte los tipos.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda y tiempo, me funciono. Repito Gracias Master